# Get message from Facebook inbox

Tags: ios, facebook, api

I have some trouble in getting messages from inbox. I used Graph API with endpoint @"me/inbox" and then used fql query like this one : SELECT thread_id, author_id, body FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id=0) 
 But in both cases result was incorrect. Firstly, it returned me messages only then, when i registered Facebook e-mail, before this i had result : "[]". Also it return not full information: 
1) return deleted messages
2) do not return messages from inbox that i receive from friends e-mail.
3) do not return some incoming messages from friend

If who had same problem or find solution, explain please, what i have done wrong. Thanks.

P.S. Excuse me for my english. I continue learning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, Facebook has rolled out their fancy new messages system without giving developers the proper API to take advantage of it.  Once they decide to release the new "unified_thread" table, it will solve your problem.  They've been saying they were going to release it for months, but I'm not holding my breath.  Until they release it...it's impossible to provide data to your users that is consistent with what they will find in their inbox.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to make a query to these table and it works. First time didn't respond table "unified_message", but later it began work too.